# How to align colon vertically using css?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I want to align **' : '** vertically, how to do that?

```
    <td>                                         
        <b>ID</b>:<asp:Label ID="ID0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br></br>
        <b>Name</b>:<asp:Label ID="Name0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br></br>
        <b>Age</b>:<asp:Label ID="Age0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br></br>
        <b>Height</b>:<asp:Label ID="Height0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Height") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br></br>
        <b>Education</b>:<asp:Label ID="Education0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Education") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Align colon vertically????? What on earth do you mean?

Comment: i want those : to be vertically aligned and centerd between those two tags, how to do that ?

Comment: i make a litlle more clear: td {vertical-align:middle;} if td is taller than content, content is vertically align in middle. it's usually defaut value of vertical-align for td If this not the question, what the hell are brs doing here :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply split the fields and values into columns.  Then all you have to do is right-align the field table-cell.

**CSS:**

```
.left-column
{
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left-column">
                        ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ID0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left-column">
                        Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Name0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left-column">
                        Age:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Age0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left-column">
                        Height:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Height0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Height") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left-column">
                        Education:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Education0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Education") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @vinay teja reddy . I have no idea how he got to guess that's what you wanted from reading your question :)

Comment: @GCyrillus - How did you not?  It was very obvious.  Just look at the markup and "aligning colons".  Reading context clues always helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use elements that have `display:inline-block` then you can use `vertical-align:middle`

EDIT

I misunderstood the question. You could set a minimum width on your `<b>` tags, but it's not fully cross-browser:

```
<style>
    p b { min-width: 50px; display:inline-block; }
</style>
<p><b>Foo</b>:</p>
<p><b>Bar</b>:</p>
```

However, as you're using a table anyway, I'd suggest using the table itself to keep things aligned

Comment: can you please show me how to do that , iam not good with css

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid markup as `colon(:)` doesn't inside `b` or `asp:Label`.
change

```
<b>ID</b>:<asp:Label ID="ID0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
```

to this

```
<b>ID :</b><asp:Label ID="ID0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: ok how to place those colons in centre and vertically aligned between those tags ?